# Windows azure microsoft fax server

Tags: azure

I have a cloud server on windows azure. Can I send faxes using microsoft fax server? Do I need to install this manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Just like with sending emails, you'll need to use a third party service which exposes an API so you can call it from your app. PamFax allows sending faxes through an API: http://www.pamfax.biz/en/developers/samples/

Comment: Thanks. I am not using Interfax: http://www.interfax.net/en/dev/webservice/samples/fax_csharp_sendcharfax